# delete entities from junction table in many to many relationship

Tags: breeze

I have a many to many relationship with a junction table.

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ContactContactGroup> ContactContactGroups { get; set; }
}

public class ContactContactGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public int ContactGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactGroup ContactGroup { get; set; }
}

public class ContactGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContactContactGroup> ContactContactGroups { get; set; }
}
```

If i delete a relation i get the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: text: Contact().Name
Message: Cannot read property 'Name' of null
```

this is my delete function:

```
   that.deleteMe = function (contactContactGroup) {    

       // Doesn't work also, duplicates entries after second deletion
       //contactGroup.ContactContactGroups.remove(contactContactGroup);

       contactContactGroup.entityAspect.setDeleted();
   };
```

here is the view:

```
  <div data-bind="foreach: ContactContactGroups">
      <div data-bind="text: Contact().Name"></div>
      <button data-bind="click: deleteMe">Delete</button>
  </div>
```

i've found a workaround with the 'with' binding from knockoutjs:

```
   that.deleteMe = function (contactContactGroup) {    
       contactGroup.ContactContactGroups.remove(contactContactGroup);
       contactContactGroup.entityAspect.setDeleted();
   };

  <div data-bind="foreach: ContactContactGroups">
      <div data-bind="with: Contact">
          <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
      </div>
      <button data-bind="click: deleteMe">Delete</button>
  </div>
```

but this seems a little odd to me.
Is this a breezejs bug or did i miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would the bug be?  Knockout requires an object to bind to and when you delete a property of that object you break the binding.

If you are using a junction table but only 'removing' one side of the before you do a custom save, it sounds like you've found the problem in your logic.  Instead of removing ContactContactGroup from the contactGroup, why don't you set both sides of the binding to null before you delete it so the view (probably) doesn't have a reason to be bound to it?

```
that.deleteMe = function (contactContactGroup) {

    contactContactGroup.Contact(null);
    contactContactGroup.ContactGroup(null);
    contactContactGroup.entityAspect.setDeleted();
    entityManager.saveChanges();
};
```

**Edit**

Looks like the problem is because of the method you are binding, you are showing the junction table in your view instead of showing the relationship between the two properties.  The problem is in Knockout still, and it's inability to display a binding that you have removed.  A more shorthand version of what you are trying to do will fix the issue you are encountering...

```
<div data-bind="foreach: ContactContactGroups">
    <div data-bind="text: $data.Contact().Name"></div>
    <button data-bind="click: deleteMe">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: When i call the function "contactContactGroup.entityAspect.setDeleted();", i get the described exception above. When i first remove the the relation entity from the array "contactGroup.ContactContactGroups.remove(contactContactGroup)", no exception will thrown, but if i call later the rejectChanges function, the entity will be duplicted.

Comment: Set the properties null first and then set it deleted then, I will update the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work also, when i null the Contact, the exception will thrown. As i have seen it, the referenced properties were nulled by the setDeleted function anyway and this confuses me.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying now and I would definitely be curious as to the logic of showing the relationship table but the problem is always going to be that you are trying to show something that isn't there.  There are a few things that you could do to make Knockout wait before re-rendering your view sans the name property while Breeze is deleting your entity but in the end if you want to continue to use it the way you are you are going to need to use a with binding or prepend $data. to the property so that it can be nulled without the view getting mad.  Answer updated...

Comment: Your "shorthand" version didn't seem to work for me (I ended up using the `with` binding like the OP did), but your answer helped me see what was going on and why it was freaking out.